# Is there any way of making my Android app intercept HTTP requests from another app?

Tags: android, http, request

Title says it all. I'm thinking about making an app where this would be needed. To be more specific the app I would need the info about requests is "TikTok".

Comment: Have you discussed your plans with your attorney?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to build a proxy server or a device based vpn and drive app traffic through either. There are open source prxy servers, device based VPNs on github some of which includes modules to intercept HTML transactions.